# Python Tkinter app freezes on bound ctrl-a IFF ctrl-a was enacted in command shell from which the script was launched

Tags: python, tkinter, bind

I have an application in which I want to use Ctrl-A to 'select all' within my canvas.  I have done :

```
 canvas.bind_all("<Control-a>", self.ctrl_a)
```

Which gets the function to call (currently a stub to print to console) executing.  However, if I select the console window from which I called the python script, and ctrl-a there, subsequent ctrl-a in my application hang.

Any idea why?

Does the ctrl-a in the console window get propagated into the running script?

Comment: You might have to run the function from a different thread.

Comment: If I launch my app with START /B (I'm on Windows at the minute) I don't get the issue.  So that IS launching in a separate thread to the console.  I suppose the ctrl-a is propagated into the python app, but would like to understand why that causes the issue.

Comment: ***"Does the ctrl-a in the console window get propagated into the running script?"***: The widget, here `Canvas` have to have the keyboard focus.

Comment: _"So that IS launching in a separate thread to the console."_ - no, it's lauching it into a separate _process_. Processes and threads are different things.

Comment: @Bryan of course.  Although I'm not sure why running and blocking the console and running in the background would be any different.  Surely the python task/process is still separate to the console task, it's just that the console task is waiting for python to terminate.

Comment: @stovfl I give the canvas the focus AFTER ctrl-a in the console window which is running the python process ... the ctrl-A in the app window then causes the app to completely hang ... well, the tkinter I presume.